# What's the difference between struct and typedef struct?

Tags: c, struct, typedef

I'm learning c programming and I was wondering what's the difference between `struct` and `typdef struct`

Because from what I saw

```c
struct Structure {
   char * name; 
   int number;
};
```

acts the same as

```c
typedef struct {
   char * name;
   int number;
} Structure;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this declaration

```
struct Structure {
   char * name; 
   int number;
};
```

there is declared a type specifier `struct Structure`.  Using it in declarations you have to write the keyword struct like

```
struct Structure s;
```

You may introduce a variable name Structure and it will not conflict with the the structure tag name because they are in different name spaces.

In this declaration

```
typedef struct {
   char * name;
   int number;
} Structure;
```

there is declared an unnamed structure for which there is introduced an alias `Structure`. You may not introduce the same name Structure for a variable in the same scope where the structure is defined.

Answer (score 0):

They are not the same.

The first creates a structure named `struct Structure`, and variables of this type are defined like this:

```
struct Structure myvar;
```

The second creates an anonymous structure and gives it the alias `Structure`.  Variables of this type are defined like this:

```
Structure myvar;
```

Also, these two structs are not interchangeable because they have different names.